# React CSS color values

Tags: css, reactjs, background-color

I am new to React and trying to build an application using the ["create-react-app"](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)
 configuration
from Facebook's page.  I am working through the example project in [React.js Succintly](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/Reactjs_Succinctly?utm_source=devfreebooks&utm_medium=medium&utm_campaign=DevFreeBooks)
but using Facebook's configuration.  I am using the Chrome Browser.

In the project there is a feature where selected cells change 
`className` designation and have a new CSS `background-color` value as a result. 
I have been having a problem with the CSS color value associated with this change; for 
some reason I am unable to enter a new CSS color value using the hex notation, 
`#018c59`.  The page only updates is if the new class has the color specified in rgb notation, 
`rgb(1, 140, 89)`.

I wasted a great deal of time identifying this as the problem and would appreciate any insight
into why only rgb values update. Is there a way to predict this constraint in the future?
Is the right answer to only use rgb color values? Has anyone seen this or know why this
happened?

Comment: Does the project change the css style with an inline style= within the jsx or does it just change the classname and use an imported CSS file?

Comment: it uses the jsx to update the name from `cell` to `cell active`.  Any ideas? and thanks....

Comment: Would you paste a small snippet showing how you added the colors?

You could also post your code on codepen or jsfiddle so I could fiddle around and get it working!

Comment: FWIW I use hex notation for colors in React, both using `style={...}` inline and CSS.

Comment: still trying to get it to work in JSBin...  https://jsbin.com/bezudemeri/edit?html,js,output

Comment: here is the working draft on JSBin;  https://jsbin.com/cuzikep/edit?html,js,output  ....and more importantly, the hex color value is working this time.  I assume this is an issue with either Facebook's `create-react-app` starting configuration or my system.  Either way it is working in JSBin and on my system with the rgb value...frustrating. Thanks for your time.

Comment: working in CodePen, again with the hex values... https://codepen.io/cgrams/pen/EmxgvN?editors=0110